# Drag and Drop Alternative

Tags: append

How can I disable blender from restarting a scene when dropping a blender model onto it? I'm looking for a way to merge models into existing scenes without using the awkward append option.

Comment: What's wrong with File > Append feature? Note that you can use Ctrl+C > Ctrl+V shortcuts to copy / paste selection though you need to have both source and destination scenes opened, also it works if no addons are enabled remapping Ctrl+C shortcut (like Copy Attibutes)

Comment: Thank You. I stand corrected. Append is the way to go.

Comment: Closing as duplicate since it seems append worked after all